# Can't create maven project in STS

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller

I can't create new maven project using this IDE Spring Tool Suite.
It show me the following errors

> CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.example.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbATz.png)

the version of my STS is 3.7.1 RELEASE
Could any one please help

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? If yes, try to configure your settings.xml file according to this tutorial : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and since I read somewhere that the error was caused by a cached file, I fixed it by deleting all the files under de .m2 repository folder. The next time I built the project I had to download all the dependencies again but it was worth it.